# show jquery validation error below the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two elements(dropdowns) which are very closely placed. These elements are required fields.

I am using jquery valiate to validate the fields. The error message are showing for both the elements and the space between the elements increases as the error message of first control is displayed near the element

```
$('#RegisterForm').validate({
        rules: {
            Country:{required: true},
            State:{required: true}
        },
        messages: {
            Country:{required: "Select Country"},
            State:{required: "Select State"}
        }
    });
```

I have tried using break before the elements as:

```
$('#RegisterForm').validate({
            rules: {
                Country:{required: true},
                State:{required: true}
            },
            messages: {
                Country:{required: "<br/>Select Country"},
                State:{required: "<br/>Select State"}
            }
        });
```

When i did so, the second element moves to next line.

How can i show the error messages just below the elements without affecting the alignment/placement of nearby elements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the **errorPlacement** option (see documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

```
$('#RegisterForm').validate({
        rules: {
            Country:{required: true},
            State:{required: true}
        },
        messages: {
            Country:{required: "Select Country"},
            State:{required: "Select State"}
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
        }
    });
```

Of course you'll have to adapt the code to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution using InsertAfter() method on my aspx webform:**

> jQuery(function () {

**//Do the Validation! Specify wrap element, add style, class and insert error message after  element by ID**

> > ```
> > $('#yourform').validate({
> >     wrapper: 'span',
> >       errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
> >         error.css({ 'color': '#FFA500', 'font-size': '0.750em' });     
> >         error.addClass("error")
> >         error.insertAfter($('[id*=element_before_error_message]'));
> >     }
> > });
> > ```

**//Applying rules**

> > $('[id*=element_to_validate]').rules('add', {
> >
> > > ```
> > >    required: true,
> > >    messages: {
> > >    required: '<br />* Some Validation Text'
> > >     }
> > > });
> > > ```
> > >
> > > });